# Can't find the error C

Tags: c, multithreading, ipc, mutex, semaphore

I have to write two threads. Each one prints 5 even/odd numbers from 1 to 100 like this (odd is `impair` in French, even is `pair`).

```
even 2,4,6,8,10
odd 1,3,5,7,9
even 12,14,16,18,20
odd 13,15,17,19,21
etc...
```

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define maxi 100

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t p;
sem_t imp;
int tour = 0;

void *pair(void *arg);
void *impair(void *arg);

int main() {
  pthread_t tidp, tidimp;

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  sem_init(&p, 0, 1);
  sem_init(&imp, 0, 1);

  pthread_create(&tidp, NULL, pair, (void *)2);
  pthread_create(&tidimp, NULL, impair, (void *)1);

  pthread_join(tidp, NULL);
  pthread_join(tidp, NULL);

  sem_destroy(&imp);
  sem_destroy(&p);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

  return 0;
}

void *pair(void *arg) {
  int i = (int)arg;
  int j, l;

  // sleep(5);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  if (!tour) {
    tour = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_wait(&imp);
  } else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  for (l = 0; l < maxi; l += 10) {
    sem_wait(&p);
    printf(" Pair  ");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j += 2) {
      printf(" %4d \t", j + i);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    printf("\n");
    sem_post(&imp);
    i += 10;
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *impair(void *arg) {
  int i = (int)arg;
  int j, l;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  if (!tour) {
    tour = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_wait(&p);
  } else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  for (l = 0; l < maxi; l += 10) {
    sem_wait(&imp);
    printf("Impair  ");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j += 2) {
      printf(" %4d \t", j + i);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    printf("\n");
    sem_post(&p);
    i += 10;
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

What I don't understand is that when I run the code, sometimes it starts with `odd`, sometimes with `even`. More particularly, when it starts with `odd` everything goes normal and I get the all numbers from 1 to 100, but when it starts with `even` sometimes I only get to 91, sometimes 93, sometimes 97.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? The screenshots below might help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not waiting for both threads to exit:

```
pthread_join(tidp, NULL);
pthread_join(tidp, NULL);
```

One of those should be `tidimp`.

Comment: Cal Norum Thank you Thank you Thank you you made my day.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes.